# searching image in another image, only return a partial result

Tags: c#, image-processing, search, pixel

The error with the following code is, it only find, partially, the first image itself.

Let me be more clear, I took a screenshot of an image, cropped it and putted it on the desktop. Then I saved the actual original image in full size (not cropped) on desktop as well.

When I run the code, it correctly detects all the coordinates of the cropped image on the desktop, however, when I open the full size image and hover it, it won't detect anything and return null, while it should be able to detect the pixels location inside the full size image as well.

I'm gonna post a video of what I mean, to be more clear:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ha3eGxWcAF8

As you see, it does not detect the pixels on the main image.
What's wrong on there?

Why it detects only the loaded cropped image, instead of a position on the screenshot based on the actual full fize image?

Code below:

```
public static Point? Find(Bitmap first, Bitmap second)
{
    if (null == first || null == second)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (first.Width < second.Width || first.Height < second.Height)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var firstArray = GetPixelArray(first);
    var secondArray = GetPixelArray(second);

    foreach (var firstLineMatchPoint in FindMatch(firstArray.Take(first.Height - second.Height), secondArray[0]))
    {
        if (IssecondPresentAtLocation(firstArray, secondArray, firstLineMatchPoint, 1))
        {
            return firstLineMatchPoint;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static int[][] GetPixelArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var result = new int[bitmap.Height][];
    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; ++y)
    {
        result[y] = new int[bitmap.Width];
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0 + y * bitmapData.Stride, result[y], 0, result[y].Length);
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return result;
}

private static IEnumerable<Point> FindMatch(IEnumerable<int[]> firstLines, int[] secondLine)
{
    var y = 0;
    foreach (var firstLine in firstLines)
    {
        for (int x = 0, n = firstLine.Length - secondLine.Length; x < n; ++x)
        {
            if (ContainSameElements(firstLine, x, secondLine, 0, secondLine.Length))
            {
                yield return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
        y += 1;
    }
}

private static bool ContainSameElements(int[] first, int firstStart, int[] second, int secondStart, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (first[i + firstStart] != second[i + secondStart])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static bool IssecondPresentAtLocation(int[][] first, int[][] second, Point point, int alreadyVerified)
{
    //we already know that "alreadyVerified" lines already match, so skip them
    for (int y = alreadyVerified; y < second.Length; ++y)
    {
        if (!ContainSameElements(first[y + point.Y], point.X, second[y], 0, second.Length))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing pixel search");

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"path_to_desktop\cropped.jpg", true);

        if (Find(bitmap, bitmap2) == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Find(bitmap, bitmap2)}.");
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // loop to detect new position
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using .Net Framework or .Net Core? Are the images something you can share?

Comment: .NET core, as for the images I Haven't quite understood what you mean. It basically searches for an image/pixels, within another image, so any will work

Comment: When you saved file did you save with correct extension for image type?

Comment: @jdweng yeah, else it would just return file doesn't exist opening it

Answer (score 0):

Edit 7.11.2020: I published a Sample Project and Video as a result of this question:

**Sample:**

https://github.com/DataJuggler/SubImageCreator

Could be called SubImageSearcher also.

**Video:**

How To Search Images Using C# And DataJuggler.PixelDatabase

https://youtu.be/JKc7QtdaxWY

Search for a sub image in a larger image using C#.

**Nuget Updates**

DataJuggler.PixelDatabase        .Net Core
DataJuggler.PixelDatabase.Net    .Net Framework

```
// Return a sub image after a PixelDatabase is loaded
Bitmap subImage = CreateSubImage(Point topLeft, Rectangle size);

// Search for a sub image inside a larger image
SearchResult result = PixelDatabase.SearchForSubImage(bitmap, searchDepth);
```

Search Result contains a Point of the top left and a score. A score of zero is a perfect match.

The sample project draws a little yellow rectangle on the Top Left hand corner if the sub image is found inside the larger image.

[image]

--
End Edit

Are the images something you can share? If not a sample image might give something to work with. If yes, tell me what you are trying to find and maybe I can find "where the pixels are you are searching for".

Another thing to watch out for is if either of the images were stretched, any difference like that could distort exact pixel colors and locations.

Are you using .Net Framework or .Net Core?

I have a Nuget package that might help you with this:

Nuget:
DataJuggler.PixelDatabase        .Net Core
DataJuggler.PixelDatabase.Net    .Net Framework

Both packages were updated yesterday.

Showing a .Net Core example

```
using DataJuggler.PixelDatabase;

// local
DataJuggler.PixelDatabase.PixelDatabase pixelDatabase = null;

// Load the pixelDatabase (you can also pass in a Bitmap or an Image also)
pixelDatabase = PixelDatabaseLoader.LoadPixelDatabase(FullImagePath, null);

// get information about a pixel at the coordinates given
PixelInformation pixel = PixelDatabase.GetPixel(x, y);
```

The pixel information object contains the Red Green and Blue colors, plus the X, Y and a lot of read only properties such as Total, BlueRed, MinMaxDifference, etc., that make querying and updating Bitmaps pretty simple.

Another thing you could do is if you know of a certain color you are looking for:

```
// color
Color color = Color.FromArgb(128, 55, 92);                                    

// get the pixels that match a certain color
List<PixelInformation> pixels = PixelDatabase.GetPixels(color);
```

That might help you locate certain groups of pixels in the image.

The same code that powers the Nuget packages is also used on my site:

https://PixelDatabase.Net

The site and the Nuget packages use a language called Bitmap Query Language, or BQL for short. This is very similar to SQL for databases if you have learned that yet.

There are lots of help and videos, but if you do any Pixel querying, I think you will find it worth the price of free.

The full source code is on Git Hub:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/PixelDatabase.Net    .Net Framework
https://github.com/DataJuggler/PixelDatabase        .Net Core

And Help is located here:
https://pixeldatabase.net/Help

And lots of videos here:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKrW5tXCPiX2PxrLPszDzlcEZwQG-Qb8r

Comment: Thanks, do you have some time to get more in depth by chat? that would help.

Comment: As for sample image, you can use those: find this: https://i.imgur.com/w6DtyYF.jpg  inside this: https://i.imgur.com/qvsnFqc.jpg

Comment: I just so happen to have this open source project and live site: https://blazorchat.com, I have to go for a run now or its too hot, but I will be back in an hour and half or so.